# Unity multiplayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

**Down Below is the code for connection approval. As shown in the image I want to turn off the Home menu GameObject(The object containing the canvas) the moment we become host or client. But In the update loop the control do not go to else statement if I am the client but it does go when I am the host. Why is that ?**

[This is the image][1]

````
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ConnectionApproval : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField ThePassword;
    public GameObject HomeMenu;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer || !NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient)
        {
            HomeMenu.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("I am " + NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer.ToString() + " " + NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient.ToString());
            HomeMenu.SetActive(false);
        }

    }

    private void ApprovalCheck(byte[] connectionData_, ulong connectionId_, NetworkManager.ConnectionApprovedDelegate callback)
    {
        bool IsApproved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(connectionData_) == ThePassword.text;
        callback(true, null, IsApproved, new Vector3(Random.Range(-3f, 3f), 1f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
    
    public void Host()
    {
        NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectionApprovalCallback += ApprovalCheck;
        NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
    }


    public void Client()
    {
        NetworkManager.Singleton.NetworkConfig.ConnectionData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ThePassword.text);
        NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
    }

}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipWR8.png
````

Comment: As written, the only way the else statement will run is if `NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer` and `NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient` are both true. Maybe you mean to use `&&` as in `if (!NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer && !NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient)` Also, your question reads "host or client" so maybe you mean `if (!NetworkManager.Singleton.IsHost && !NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient)`

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you for answering. The **&&** condition worked. Don't know why I was unseeing it. :-)